# Xamarin Android VideoView player controls do not track player position

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a ListView in Xamarin Forms app with videoplayer as ListViewItem. The video player implemented with native renderer. It works fine, but if i move videoplayer (scrolling listview) when player controls is shown, the controls are not following player position.

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfbXd.jpg)

This is some parts of the renderer. I'm not sure where is the problem so i don't know what code i should paste

```
public class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, ARelativeLayout>
```

```
videoView = new VideoView(Context);
ARelativeLayout relativeLayout = new ARelativeLayout(Context);
relativeLayout.AddView(videoView);
ARelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
new ARelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
videoView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
videoView.Prepared += OnVideoViewPrepared;
SetNativeControl(relativeLayout);
```

```
mediaController = new MediaController(Context);
mediaController.SetMediaPlayer(videoView);
videoView.SetMediaController(mediaController);
```

Comment: if you have a scrollview with 3 video players inside, it has the same behaviour? or only on ListView?

Comment: i don't know but the answer just works

Comment: glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a workaround :

create a custom MediaController in Droid project:

```
class MyController : MediaController
{
    private Context _context;
    public MyController(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    private bool _isShowing { get; set; } = false;
    public override bool IsShowing { get { return _isShowing; } }

    public override void Show()
    {
        base.Show();
        _isShowing = true;

        ViewGroup parent = ((ViewGroup)this.Parent);
        parent.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    public override void Hide()
    {
        base.Hide();
        _isShowing = false;

       ViewGroup parent = ((ViewGroup)this.Parent);
        parent.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    }
}
```

then in your **VideoPlayerRenderer** ,set the MediaController in `OnVideoViewPrepared` method:

```
private void OnVideoViewPrepared(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyController mc = new MyController(videoView.Context);
        videoView.SetMediaController(mc);
        FrameLayout f = (FrameLayout)mc.Parent;
        Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, Android.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
        ((LinearLayout)f.Parent).RemoveView(f);
        ((Android.Widget.RelativeLayout)videoView.Parent).AddView(f, lp);
        mc.SetAnchorView(videoView);
    }
```